# How to create a dynamic form for adding a collection of data?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, textbox

To put simple:

1. I have a database with two tables...
2. I use a datamodel to connect to the database
3. I create two classes which store my methods and properties for the two tables
4. I create one form for gathering information on table 1 and click next (hyperlinks to another page)
5. I pass the table 1's ID through and then I have a problem. The data submitted for table 2 is inter-changeable meaning it will vary how much data will be submitted for table 2 based on the id of table

My question is, how can I create a dynamic webform which will allow users to click an add button and it adds another textbox or a copy of the one that is currently on the page? I then want to put them into a list and then send them off to the table 1 database using an insert method from the datamodel.

To make it simple for point [5] say you have a book, name, author, publisher etc. That could be an example for table 1. But for table 2 I then want the user to put each page number into seperate textboxes... Now i know this is a bad example but am trying to get the point accross in that you couldn't just have a given set of textboxes static to the page because each book has different amount of pages.

Any examples would get great.

Comment: of you are just asking if it is possible.. this is very much possible

Comment: Ok, a little guidance would be nice ;) obviously no code but an explanation would be nice

Answer (score 1):

use a reapeater control and put a place holder in the item template and bind the ids from table1. Use Itemdatabound event to capture each row and add the necessary number of controls (using loadcontrol or if its just textbox then create an instance of it) from table2 and add it to the place holder.